# "An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest was not found" using docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to dockerize an `an angular aspnet core 2.2 webapi` using the following dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2.105 AS build
WORKDIR /src

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ["Fightplan_v1/Fightplan_v1.csproj", "Fightplan_v1/"]
COPY ["Fightplan_v1.Autogenerate/Fightplan_v1.Autogenerate.csproj", "Fightplan_v1.Autogenerate/"]
COPY ["Fightplan_v1.Autogenerate.Test/Fightplan_v1.Autogenerate.Test.csproj", "Fightplan_v1.Autogenerate.Test/"]
COPY ["Fightplan_v1.Database/Fightplan_v1.Database.csproj", "Fightplan_v1.Database/"]
COPY ["Fightplan_v1.Helpers/Fightplan_v1.Helpers.csproj", "Fightplan_v1.Helpers/"]
COPY ["Fightplan_v1.Jobs/ConvertImagestoBlob/Fightplan_v1.ConvertImagestoBlob.csproj", "Fightplan_v1.Jobs/ConvertImagestoBlob/"]
COPY ["Fightplan_v1.Models/Fightplan_v1.Models.csproj", "Fightplan_v1.Models/"]
COPY ["Fightplan_v1.Shared/Fightplan_v1.Shared.csproj", "Fightplan_v1.Shared/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Fightplan_v1/Fightplan_v1.csproj"

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Fightplan_v1"
RUN dotnet build "Fightplan_v1.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Fightplan_v1.csproj" -c Release -o /app

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .

EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Fightplan_v1.dll"]
```

The build command used is:

```
docker build -f .\fp.dockerfile -t test .
```

The build goes through fine but when I try to run it using:

```
docker run -p 5100:80 -it test
```

I get the following error:
[image]

I have tried:

1. Adding  `-r linux-x64` to the end of publish to define the runtime: `RUN dotnet publish "Fightplan_v1.csproj" -c Release -o /app -r linux-x64`
2. Adding `<PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>` to my `.csproj` file

None of the above fixes work unfortunately.

Since this is combined poject of an angular application and a webapi I might be missing some installations/dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying the runtime files from wrong layer

```
COPY --from=build /app .
```

Try to change it to

```
COPY --from=publish /app .
```

Also, you probably need to separate out path in build and publish steps:

```
RUN dotnet build "Fightplan_v1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
RUN dotnet publish "Fightplan_v1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
```

and then copy runtime files from the publish folder

```
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
```

**Edit.** Basically, you need to copy `publish` artifacts into runtime, not `build`. Build will produce deps.json, which will lists all external dependencies, and during runtime this libraries are resolving using NuGet cache, if it is empty you will see an error. To copy dependencies along with project files you need to run `publish`.
So I assume, that theoretically `dotnet build` can be omitted, and is using only to discover compilation errors on early stage of docker build.

Comment: Take in mind that it would not build you angular application, only asp net. You should  add more steps to Dockerfile to build it using node image and copy it to runtime layer.

Comment: I am now facing another problem which I have seen before but haven't found a solution for yet.. It would be great if you have the time to take a look at it. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58913262/err-connection-refused-angular-and-dotnet-core-webapi-using-docker